# Laravel images loading on localhost but not on server

Tags: laravel

I have my application setup locally and on an ubuntu server. Locally everything works fine and images are loading just fine but not on the server. The image path is the same but on the server I see the `404 Not Found` page when trying to see an image. Could someone point me in the right direction? Do I need to do some configuration on the server to get it to work?

Comment: Can I see 404 full url?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto http://localhost:8000/skill-icons/ac_skill_01_1.png and http://example.com/skill-icons/ac_skill_01_1.png

Comment: Wait, is this assets? not uploaded files?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written to display the image?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I created a folder under `/public/skill-icons/...` where I have images, not uploaded files.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I use the following code `<img src={"/skill-icons/" + props.skill.image} height="44" />`

Comment: @MA instead of using that you should `asset_url()` I guess also you need create symlink for image url, have you created the symlink?